# Segmentation fault whrn trying to sort the array by quick sort

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I'm making a program of **quick sort** which prints the sorted elements of the arry but when I run the code I get **segmentation fault**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int partition(int arr[],int left,int right,int pivot) {

    while(left <= right) {
        while(arr[left] < pivot) {
            left++;
        }
        while(arr[right] > pivot) {
            right--;
        }
        if(left <= right) {
            swap(arr[left],arr[right]);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    return left;
}

void quick_sort(int arr[],int left,int right) {

    int pivot = arr[(left+right)/2];
    int index = partition(arr,left,right,pivot);
    quick_sort(arr,left,index-1);
    quick_sort(arr,index,right);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    quick_sort(arr,0,size-1);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting a soted arrray of elements which are hardcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to top your quick_sort function

```
if (left >= right)
    return;
```